# Swift setting Badge Value for UITabBarItem

Tags: swift, swift2, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I'm attempting to add a badge alert label like the one in the screenshot attached.

[image]

I've tried to search for titles, labels uitabbar items but I'm stuck.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to refer to the red badge with the white ‘1’? “an alert label” isn’t really specific ;)

Comment: Haha, I thought so too, but that's the best way I can think of to describe it. Yes, that red badge with the 1 is what I want.

Comment: Sorry been very hectic lately at work, I'll take a look once I have the time and upvote it. Cheers

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**Xcode 7.2.1 Swift 2.1.1**

You just have to set the badgeValue for your desired UITabBarItem as follow:

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[4].badgeValue = "1"   // this will add "1" badge to your fifth tab bar item


// or like this to apply it to your first tab
tabBarController?.tabBar.items?.first?.badgeValue = "1st"

// or to apply to your second tab
tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[1].badgeValue = "2nd"

// to apply it to your last tab
tabBarController?.tabBar.items?.last?.badgeValue = "Last"
```

To remove a badge from the UITabBarItem just add nil value to it

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.items?.first?.badgeValue = nil
```

Comment: why tabBarController for me is nil?

Comment: Found the answer. Because I was already inside a UITabBarController, so I had to omit tabBarController from the above code.